# How to back up my entire system?

Tags: backup

If I want to make a backup of my entire OS (including but not just my home directory), how do I go about this?

Is it as simple as backing up everything in `/` and then when if I suffer a crash, just copying the files back over?
Will this cover grub, and how do I actually do this when the system is inoperable?

Comment: you may want to take a look at this question for backup tools http://askubuntu.com/q/2596/

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? In most cases it is *your files* you will want to backup - the rest of the system is for most people easy to reinstall from the Ubuntu CD.

Comment: Because i hate reinstalling all my apps and PPAs, icons and themes. My HD crashes the installer sometime and I just generally hate installing everything from scratch.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

**FILES**

Refer to this howto: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087

In simple terms, the backup command is:

```bsh
sudo tar czf /backup.tar.gz \
    --exclude=/backup.tar.gz \
    --exclude=/dev \
    --exclude=/mnt \
    --exclude=/proc \
    --exclude=/sys \
    --exclude=/tmp \
    --exclude=/media \
    --exclude=/lost+found \
    /
```

Add more `--exclude=` parameters if you need to.

It will create an archive of all your files at `/backup.tar.gz`, which should be copied to another computer or drive.

To restore your files when the system goes pear-shaped, use a Live CD. Mount the bad system under `/media` or `/mnt` and then run `tar xf /path/to/drive/with/backup.tar.gz -C /mnt` (or `/media`).

**GRUB**

This will not cover GRUB, however you can easily reinstall it by following this [guide here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-seven-on-ubuntu-10-10/6321#6321). You only need to do **steps Three and Four**.

Comment: Great post! Thanks a lot that pretty much answers all my questions

Comment: I am experimenting your command with external NTFS here http://askubuntu.com/q/788272/25388 but with failures.

Comment: Tried this one, but it seems too much waiting to mount the resulting archive (like 5 hours). Similar approach is with SquashFS, but much, much faster, see http://askubuntu.com/a/857845/98715

Comment: why exclude /sys?

Comment: How big is the tar file usually? For example I have 90GB of data in "/". But the backing up process (making the backup.tar.gz) stopped because of lack of space..
Is there a way to create the backup.tar.gz file in an external drive?

Comment: @SDsolar: because it's a _virtual filesystem_, just like `/dev`and `/proc`: https://askubuntu.com/a/720473/11015

Comment: @ArkyaChatterjee: Or course... just mount your external drive and change `/backup.tar.gz` to whatever is your mount point, like `/media/backup//backup.tar.gz`

Comment: The OP explicitely says "including (...) my home directory" but you are excluding the home directories of all users (--exclude=/home). Am I missing something here?

Comment: The quoted command has a missing space prior to `--exclude=/dev`

Comment: So essentially the answer is just "copy everything (as sudo), however you want, but exclude `/dev`, `/mnt`, `/proc`, `/sys` and `/lost+found`". Good to know. This excludes stuff like `/dev/urandom`, which would copy an infinite amount, or `/proc/kcore`, which is 128TB on my system, but includes for example `/usr/bin` with most programs in it.

Comment: Why is this so much slower than `dd`? Can we not just use `dd` to clone the entire disk?

Comment: `tar -cvpzf /backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /` will do what you want without needing to add all those other `--exclude` directories

Comment: For a more up to date list of files see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR This doc also mentions `/run` and `/media` among other things.

Comment: Does this consider hidden files/folders as well?

Comment: Note that there is a trap here for those with multiple partitions. Users have to mount them ALL, otherwise the system is not restored.

Answer (score 32):

To clone your system to another system. Or make a backup. In terminal type:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > ubuntu-files
```

This command makes a file list of all installed packages in your system (and stores it in present working directory). Backup this file in hdd, email, etc...(this file is very small).

In the freshly installed ubuntu system run:

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections <./ubuntu-files (will set it up and)

apt-get -y update
apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

This will install only those packages you had installed (with `apt-get`) in the old system.

Alternatively, you could back up all the `.deb` packages from `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and install them manually using:

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

And after that running an update cycle later.

Comment: This indeed an interesting strategy. 
how to go about the second way under (OR) you proposed. Back them up by copying them?

Comment: @MohammedJoraid I guess, or by making an archive (.zip or .tar.*) file and copying that.

Comment: Does not back up /home.

Answer (score 31):

Noone noticed [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/). It makes a complete image of your hard drive, so it backups **absolutely everything**. It's as easy as burning an iso or creating a bootable flash drive.

The actual backup takes a while, but is the most reliable.

Comment: How can you it be better than evgeny's proposal? Is there some management etc tools?

Comment: Can not recommend clonezilla. I just tried it and got this error: https://sourceforge.net/p/clonezilla/discussion/Clonezilla_live/thread/1bfa4f2e/ and seems like nothing is being done about it

Comment: Clonezilla is really great! It's use-case is a bit different tho. I used it to clone my harddrive to an external. However, it is a full clone of the whole disk, including empty space. It is an exact mirror, which is great, but a different use-case for backups.

Comment: I can also comment to say that Clonezilla is broken and not useful as it clones empty space.

Comment: I've been using Clonezilla for some years. Works well for me.

Comment: Clonezilla does not clone empty space. It's a great tool with the only downside being that you have to boot into it.

Comment: Also called a disk snapshot or a system image.

Answer (score 22):

Here is a solution I use with SquashFS. It is quite similar to TAR.GZ solution proposed earlier, but has some major benefits.

SquashFS is a compressed file system, which is completely stored in one file. This file can be mounted to an existing system and accessed in a usual way, like any other partition. The difference to TAR.GZ is that SquashFS is a full-blown file system with random access to files, while TAR is just one big concatenated file.

This means that if you want to mount some large backup of your whole file system, for TAR.GZ it would take like 5 hours (in my experience) and for SquashFS it would take just minutes/seconds. The same is true also for the compression/backup operation, SquashFS is many times faster.

**UPDATE 2017-01-31**:
It appears that not only can you mount squashfs file, but also open it as a usual archive with familiar apps like File Roller on Linux and 7-Zip on Windows, etc.

So here is a command I use to back up my root folder:

```
sudo mksquashfs / /path/to/backup/hdd/root-backup.sqsh -e home media dev run mnt proc sys tmp
```

where "-e" switch excludes folders you want to exclude (like virtual and external Linux folders in my example).

After the backup is done, I can now mount it:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/root_backup
sudo mount /path/to/backup/hdd/root-backup.sqsh /mnt/root_backup -t squashfs -o loop
```

Now just wait couple minutes (depending on size of the archive) and enjoy all your files at /mnt/root_backup folder.

Same can be done for /home/myname folder, e.g.

```
sudo mksquashfs /home/myname /path/to/backup/hdd/home-backup.sqsh -e Dropbox GoogleDrive
```

I exclude Dropbox and GoogleDrive here to avoid any potential problems in the future, in case I restore those folders from backup and they become messing with the actual files in the cloud.

Check more info at http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SquashFS-HOWTO/creatingandusing.html

Comment: Excellent answer. I used this to create my own script that lives on my NAS drive which is connected via NFS. Answered separately below since it has code.

Comment: Note that SquashFS does not support ACLs (see the section titled "Xattr Table" [here](https://dr-emann.github.io/squashfs/) for an explanation). Attempting to run `mksquashfs` on directories that have ACLs defined results in an `Unrecognised xattr prefix system.posix_acl_access` error. More details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219809/83446) and a possible patch [here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/1/25/117).

Comment: It might be obvious but the sample command specifically excludes the home folder, which isn't what the OP wanted. But it's a great solution, nonetheless!

Answer (score 13):

We can also do backup of system with rsync & exclude files & folders that we don't want. Here is the following command to do this :

```
#rsync -aAXv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} /* /path/to/backup/folder
```

Using the **`-aAX`** set of options, the files are transferred in archive mode, ensuring that symbolic links, devices, permissions and ownerships, modification times, ACLs and extended attributes are preserved

The **`--exclude`** option will cause files that match the given patterns to be excluded.

**REFERENCE : [Full system backup with rsync](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rsync#Full_system_backup)**

Comment: Here you should mention to **exclude** `/path/to/backup/folder` as well.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/) to create a bootable live CD/DVD image. This will install like a normal Ubuntu CD.

To install Remastersys, you first need to add a repository:

```
deb http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/repository karmic/
```

You can then install it from the Software Centre as usual.

Once installed, use it to make a 'dist' backup. This means that user data will be excluded from the ISO image.

[image: remastersys UI]

This is often used to create custom distributions but is still useful for the backup task you have in mind. One caveat is that it may fail if the contents of `/` (minus user data in `/home`) takes up too much memory because the ISO file format can only hold ~4GB data. Remastersys uses a file system called squashfs to compress your data so you should be OK with up to ~8GB.

Comment: I tried this but last time it got too big so taring / excluding the directories im not interested in is better for me, then when i backup i dont have to wait for the CD as my HD will be quicker thanks for the advice though

Answer (score 6):

Try [Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html).
With that program you can do liveCD (just the same as Ubuntu installation iso file) of your system with ability to install it on hard drive. Works pretty simple (if you know how to burn iso to USB/CD/DVD).
Works perfectly on my 11.10 and 11.04, and older ones as well.

Installation:
edit file  `/etc/apt/sources.list`
add: `# Remastersys`
`deb http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/repository karmic/`   and save
Then run in terminal:
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install remastersys`

Answer (score 5):

**TimeShift.**

TimeShift protects your system by taking incremental snapshots of the file system at regular intervals. These snapshots can be restored later to bring your system to the exact state it was in at the time when the snapshot was taken.

Open the terminal and run the following command

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install timeshift
```

Screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I turned [afrish's excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/857845/713611) into a script for myself. Thought it could be useful for those wishing to automate it. The nice thing is that since the script can live on the NAS it will only execute if it's connected.

The script (can be copied to any location - preferably the NAS itself) and will build the backups in the same folder.

### Backups Script

make_backups_root_and_home.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then echo "Please run as root"
  exit
fi

log="log.txt"
power=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/AC/online)
start_date=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)

if (( $power == 1 )); then
    echo "Starting backup $log at $start_date" >> $log

    # ROOT IMAGE
    root_backup_file=$start_date-root-backup.sqsh
    sudo mksquashfs / $root_backup_file -e home media dev run mnt proc sys tmp nfs

    # ALL HOMES IMAGE
    home_backup_file=$start_date-home-backup.sqsh
    sudo mksquashfs /home $home_backup_file -e Dropbox GoogleDrive

    finish_date=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
    echo "Completed $root_backup_file and $home_backup_file at $finish_date" >> $log
else
    echo "Power is not plugged in... skipped on $start_date" >> $log
fi
```

Don't forget to `chmod +x make_backups_root_and_home.sh`!

---

### Linux Cronjob

To enable the cronjob:

```
sudo su
crontab -e
```

For Sunday at 1am, append:

```
00 01 * * sun  /nas_path/to/your/make_backups_root_and_home.sh >> /nas_path/to/your/log.txt 2>&1
```

---

### Testing Backups!

As with all good backups, they should be tested! 
Finally, we can create a script to mount the last available backup (since they are ordered by date).

mount_last_backup.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo mkdir -p /mnt/root_backup
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/root_home

#UMOUNT ANY
sudo umount /mnt/root_backup
sudo umount /mnt/home_backup

last_root=$(ls -Xrt -1 *root-backup* | head -n 1)
last_home=$(ls -Xrt -1 *home-backup* | head -n 1)

sudo mount $last_root /mnt/root_backup -t squashfs -o loop
sudo mount $last_home /mnt/home_backup -t squashfs -o loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good tutorial using [PartImage](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/partimage).

Answer (score 2):

If you hard-disk where Ubuntu is installed isn't too big, you can try booting from a live cd (any linux distro will do) and running:

```
    dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/external/hardisk/mybackupfile
```

This makes a backup of your whole hard-disk, not just Ubuntu, and it'll also do all the empty bytes, but it's the only solution I can think of.
To restore the backup, use:

```
  dd if=/path/to/external/harddisk/mybackupfile of=/dev/sda
```

Comment: so how would I restore my Ubuntu distro from a copy om my whole HDD? Because you can't do that...

Comment: @Alvar by storing the backup on an external/cloud drive and running it from a live CD/DVD/USB image.

Answer (score 1):

go to ubuntu software center
find **Déjà Dup backup manger**
install it``
run it and give path where to backup your data
select files to be backup
make a back up

later on you can chose backup by giving location of your external hard drive
gud luck
source
[https://launchpad.net/deja-dup]

Comment: I want to backup my entire system not just my music or videos.

Comment: @Alvar you can select the "/" or "File System" and can back that up (that is the ENTIRE SYSTEM).

Comment: how do I install it? how do I backup my system with it?

Comment: It does seem to be reliable at all. Just read some user reviews here https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/deja-dup/

Comment: @ILIV well yeah, the review sucks. That's good to know. 
Guess it's could be used for single files and music stuff maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools like [Bacula Community](https://bacula.org) or [Bacula Enterprise](https://www.baculasystems.com/enterprise-backup-solution-with-bacula-systems/linux-server-backup-software).
The difference between them is that community version doesn't support bare metal restores when you don't need to re-install the system and just purely recover it after the major crash.

Answer (score 1):

You can backup your entire Ubuntu installation to another partition with this answer:

- [Bash script to clone active Ubuntu Partition to another partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-backkup-clone-ubuntu-to-another-partition/1028605#1028605)

Advantages of this technique:

- You can continue using the system while it is being backed up. Care must be taken that you are only using web browser apps, office apps, watching videos, etc. and **not** database apps like accounting or SQL.
- Virtual file systems are not backed up. They are recreated on each boot up so they are useless to backup in the first place.
- The first backup may take an hour but daily backups do not copy files that haven't changed so they may only take a few minutes.
- You can reboot and use the backup. This is beneficial if you want to try something dangerous that might break the system such as a Ubuntu Version upgrade untested in your environment.
- If you totally break your production environment you can reboot into your clone and copy it back over using the same script.
- Grub is automatically updated with proper UUID entries.
- `/etc/fstab` is automatically updated with proper UUID entries.

Answer (score 1):

**Systemback – Restore Ubuntu Desktop and Server To Previous State** *(Free tool)*

*"Systemback is a free utility that can be used to backup and restore Ubuntu-like systems. It is somewhat similar to MS Windows’s “System restore” option. Using Systemback, we can easily create backup of a Ubuntu desktop or server system, and restore them to the previous state whenever we want. It creates one or more restore points date and time-wise, and displays the most recent restore points at the top. Not only restore points, we can also create the complete backup of your live system including user configuration files and data as ISO, and save them in an external hard disk."*

- Backup the system with or without user configuration files and data
- Restore system to any previous working state
- Copy files/folders from one partition to another
- Create the live Ubuntu system as ISO, and boot your system using it in-case of any problems
- Copy files/folders from one partition to another
- Create the live Ubuntu system as ISO, and boot your system using it in-case of any problems
- Upgrade our system to next available version etc.

[Link to website describing the install procedure.](https://www.ostechnix.com/systemback-restore-ubuntu-desktop-and-server-to-previous-state/)

Answer (score 0):

[Crashplan](http://www.crashplan.com/consumer/details.html) will back up all your system files and data and allow you to recover it - either on your current PC or allow you to adopt it to another install.

You can back up to their online system, another computer or any attached hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I have found you a detailed and recent how to on using Clonezilla. Clonezilla will let you make an image of your complete system including all hard drive partitions etc and later restore it.

The tutorial is at http://geekyprojects.com/cloning/how-to-use-clonezilla-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on a Ubuntu 18.04 desktop, and only requires 'Disks' (gnome-disk-utility), gparted and standard grub commands.

## Backup

- Create an 8GB partition on a drive and install Ubuntu (minimal install) - call it **utilities**

  - Install **gparted**
- Within this system ..

  - Run **Disks**, pick production system partition, and choose **Create partition image**
  - Save the image to *ddMMMYYYY.img* on any partition on the computer

## Restore

- Within the **utilities** system, run 'Disks' and click on the partition to restore to

  - choose **Restore partition image**, and choose the image
- Run **gparted**

  - There might be unallocated space in the new partition

    - **Partition -> Check (and repair)**, regardless
  - The UUID will be the same as the original partition, so if the original partition still exists on the computer, you need ..

    - **Partition -> New UUID**
  - Take note of the **UUID** - eg. ba5b7f3a-54d2-4325-80e5-e7a159900d3f
  - Take note of the restored **partition** - eg. /dev/sda6

### fstab update

- Skip to *grub update* below if you have **not** created a new UUID
- Run **Files** (ie. nautilus)

  - Click **+ Other Locations**
  - Click on the device/partition - eg./dev/sda6
- Run ..

```
      df -hT
      # you will get something like ..
      /dev/sda6 xx xx /media/fred/ba5b7f3a-54d2-4325-80e5-e7a159900d3f/etc/fstab
```

- paste in the last entry to produce a command like so ..

```
  sudo vi /media/fred/ba5b7f3a-54d2-4325-80e5-e7a159900d3f/etc/fstab
```

- Change the ''/'' entry in ''fstab'' to use this UUID

### grub update

- Run the following (assuming that your master boot record is on /dev/sda) ..

```
  # ensure all systems are found
  sudo os-prober
  # generate /boot/grub/grub.cfg
  sudo update-grub
  # search for root=UUID and check that the new UUID is used in some of these
  # if not, try sudo grub-mkconfig, seems to get it right eventually
  less /boot/grub/grub.cfg
  # update the master boot record
  sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

- Reboot and go into the restored system
- Check that you **really are in the restored system** - note the ''/'' line

```
df -hT | grep ext4
/dev/sda6      ext4       29G  6.1G   22G  23% /
/dev/sdb6      ext4      112G   86G   22G  81% /data
/dev/sda4      ext4      1.6T  377G  1.1T  26% /sata
```

### final grub update from the new system

- Run this from the new system, so that this system becomes the default in the boot menu (assuming that your master boot record is on /dev/sda) ..

```
  sudo os-prober
  sudo update-grub
  sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 0):

A side note: Make sure permissions and owernship are preserved when copying or your backed up copy will be unusable ([annoyingly, reinstalling is then the fastest way to recover](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/wrongly-set-chmod-777-problems)).

A tar file like that used in the accepted answer will preserve permissions and ownership (see tar manpage and [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1083144/537480)). [NTFS drives support permissions *if* mounted with `permissions`.](https://askubuntu.com/a/74851/477026) FAT has no support. For other filesystems, rather than messing around with mounting options and `/etc/fstab`, you should use tar and rest assured permissions/ownership is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend my solution which was created with the goal of minimizing space requirements: https://github.com/vbence/osbackup

It can restore a bootable system to an empty media as long as you only use the following technologies.

It covers:

- Partition tables of block devices (through sfdisk).
- Raid arrays compatible with mdadm.
- Logical volumes using LVM.
- Encrypted devices using dm_crypt (the user will be prompted for the new passphrases).
- File systems, as long as they are ext* or vfat.
- Grub boot loader.

Answer (score -2):

I use a program called [Back In Time](http://backintime.le-web.org/) that's similar to Apple's Time Machine.

It's easy to tell it where you want your backups to go and how often to do the backup.

Back In Time is in the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: That doesn't explain how to backup my system and how to restore it at all. When i can't even boot up back in time won't be able to help. If you can suggest how to use backup in time in this way I would be appreciative. Cheers

Comment: Back in time uses is a frontend for rsync.  You'll have to have Ubuntu installed to use it.  I agree with fluteflute's comment above that it's easier to backup your files.  That's what I thought you wanted.

Comment: I already backup my files ;) The amount of times i render ubuntu inoperable its easier to either reinstall or revert to a backup than fix the problem (generally i need it fixed as I have work to do in between fiddling and breaking!)

Comment: Right. I tried back in time to setup an automatic backup but i get a whole bunch of errors. Most like this: (its just a small fraction, and im running in root mode)

Comment: [E] Error: rsync: read errors mapping "/sys/module/videodev/sections/.altinstr_replacement": No data available (61)

Comment: The backup commands noted above would probably work best for you.  I only suggested Back in Time as a frontend for the rsync, etc.  You can choose what you want to make a backup of, including all of the system files.

Comment: Back In Time is just awful, especially the GUI. It routinely crashes for me and doesn't show any progress or status information, so it's unclear when it's actually running.