# My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?

Tags: wireless

### Your situation

- You have successfully installed Ubuntu.
- You have just downloaded and booted Ubuntu live media.

  The latest LTS (see also [HWE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe)) or latest non-LTS release are preferred. See the list of [Ubuntu releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) that are currently supported.)
- You upgraded your Ubuntu installation to the latest release that the software updater offered you. WiFi worked before, but not now on the new release.
- You [migrated your existing Ubuntu installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254785/migrating-the-volume) to new hardware.

### Your problem

- The wireless of your laptop or desktop is not working. You tried switching the wireless switch off and on and you tried rebooting several times, but you don't see any WiFi access points.
- You can see your wireless access point, but you cannot establish a connection.
- You want to analyze the problem, but you don't know where to start or what information you can provide.

**This question and answer was written to give people the wireless script that will provide the information needed in most cases to diagnose their wireless issue's.**

### Related questions

- [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](https://askubuntu.com/q/14008)

Comment: What is the output of `sudo rfkill list`?

Comment: Before you run an arbitrary command, especially w/`sudo` make sure you know what it does. So try `man rfkill` first!

Comment: I just want to point out that there is nothing wrong with having your question closed as a duplicate. cc @LiveWireBT

Comment: Here is what we probably want to do: Close this as a duplicate of that hardware problems question. Here's the thing though - duplicates are signposts, so others will be able to find it. Duplicates create google juice, and improve the internets!

Comment: May I just add that output of `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8 && ping -c 4 google.com` is pretty handy sometimes too ?

Comment: here is the link to my machines wifi-info log. can somebody please tell me what is wrong here http://paste.ubuntu.com/12426133/

Comment: if you have MediaTek MT7921 Wifi adapter - this helped me a lot: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=399594

Answer (score 94, accepted):

## Wireless Info Script

The easiest and most complete method of gathering information to help diagnose wireless issues is to run the [wireless info script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) we created at the Ubuntu Forums to collect all the most common information needed while *masking all sensitive data*.

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run these commands:

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
  chmod +x wireless-info &&
  ./wireless-info
```

This will create the file "wireless-info.txt" at the location it is run from, and depending on its size, an additional archive called "wireless-info.tar.gz". Sensitive information like MAC addresses and WPA/WEP keys are masked automatically.

**If you cannot connect to the internet** with the affected system, including via a wired connection, you will have to move files between it and a system connected to the internet. A USB stick would likely be the easiest method for this.

Post the results on [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) or [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/), and link to it here in your question.

Further details on the script: [GitHub page](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info).

Here is an example of the information that the script will collect:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 02 May 2015 23:04 CDT -0500

Booted last: 01 May 2015 00:44 CDT -0500

Script from: 30 Apr 2015 17:23 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-49-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 24 19:29:48 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

GNOME Flashback (Compiz)

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b5] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0647]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:6617]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c18 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

acer_wmi               32522  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 acer_wmi
ath9k                 164164  0 
ath9k_common           13551  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              453856  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    28698  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              630669  1 ath9k
cfg80211              484040  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211
wmi                    19177  1 acer_wmi
video                  19476  2 i915,acer_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          inet addr:192.168.43.63  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2600:100c:b004:3fa3:2216:d8ff:fe89:5871/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::2216:d8ff:fe89:5871/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2600:100c:b004:3fa3:9db3:d3ca:cda7:6666/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:227572 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:200363 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:162556355 (162.5 MB)  TX bytes:31143668 (31.1 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"scubby"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point:    
          Bit Rate=12 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-33 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:150   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
#ubuntuforums-mods
##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [scubby] -------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ath9k
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           54 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    ATT9156:         Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37 WPA2
    taarakian:       Infra, , Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 29 WPA2
    NETGEAR:         Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 19 WPA WPA2
    suddenlink.net-1140: Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 7 WPA2
    RSS-351540:      Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 12 WPA2
    suddenlink.net-9572: Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 12 WPA WPA2
    SJI:             Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA2
    NETGEAR70:       Infra, , Freq 2447 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 5 WPA2
    SUDDENLINK.NET-6E3D: Infra, , Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WEP
    *scubby:          Infra, , Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 85 WPA2
    SJI Guest:       Infra, , Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 12
    ATT677:          Infra, , Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 24 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.43.63
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.43.1

    DNS:             192.168.43.1

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            tg3
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DIRECT-roku-067-072A4B]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DIRECT-roku-067-072A4B | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=DIRECT-roku-067-072A4B | mac-address=
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Chicago (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

##### iwlist scan #######################

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Larry"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000028511003
                    Extra: Last beacon: 20ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ATT9156"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000371b6618537
                    Extra: Last beacon: 20ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"SJI Guest"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000149eca5197
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2304ms ago
          Cell 04 - Address: 
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=20/70  Signal level=-90 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"taarakian"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000268fbeb2d80
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1996ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: 
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=37/70  Signal level=-73 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"SUDDENLINK.NET-6E3D"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001765a3e4af3
                    Extra: Last beacon: 20ms ago
          Cell 06 - Address: 
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=23/70  Signal level=-87 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"NETGEAR"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000092d136ec9e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 20ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-49-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     274594FBD61F5DF88102A4C
depends:        ath9k_hw,mac80211,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A2:F2:B9:84:B0:F0:3D:B6:0B:A1:EA:08:10:49:37:4C:1A:C3:D9:02
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-49-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     93644B269B570BC55CF5154
depends:        ath,ath9k_hw
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A2:F2:B9:84:B0:F0:3D:B6:0B:A1:EA:08:10:49:37:4C:1A:C3:D9:02
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-49-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     65C14EF588BF1A68181643C
depends:        ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A2:F2:B9:84:B0:F0:3D:B6:0B:A1:EA:08:10:49:37:4C:1A:C3:D9:02
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-49-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     88A67C5359B02C5A710AFCF
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A2:F2:B9:84:B0:F0:3D:B6:0B:A1:EA:08:10:49:37:4C:1A:C3:D9:02
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-49-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     29A87AE7782ED3657631C32
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A2:F2:B9:84:B0:F0:3D:B6:0B:A1:EA:08:10:49:37:4C:1A:C3:D9:02
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-49-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     176113E009F723E69BE9BAB
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A2:F2:B9:84:B0:F0:3D:B6:0B:A1:EA:08:10:49:37:4C:1A:C3:D9:02
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
ps_enable: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/power.d/disable_wol] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/laptop-mode] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pci_devices] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pcie_aspm] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/sched-powersave] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/usb_bluetooth] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/wireless] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/xfs_buffer] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x16b5 (tg3)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x168c:0x0032 (ath9k)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
# USB device 0x:0x (rndis_host)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

##### dmesg #############################

[53764.123272] wlan0: deauthenticating from  by local choice (reason=3)
[53766.341705] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
[53769.663996] ath9k 0000:03:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[53770.839058] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[53772.588289] wlan0: authenticate with 
[53772.612650] wlan0: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[53772.614687] wlan0: authenticated
[53772.614954] wlan0: AP has invalid WMM params (AIFSN=1 for ACI 2), disabling WMM
[53772.615474] wlan0: associate with  (try 1/3)
[53772.618314] wlan0: RX AssocResp from  (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[53772.618513] wlan0: associated
[53772.618541] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[53772.771949] wlan0: deauthenticating from  by local choice (reason=2)
[53772.783893] wlan0: authenticate with 
[53772.801865] wlan0: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[53772.803896] wlan0: authenticated
[53772.804020] wlan0: AP has invalid WMM params (AIFSN=1 for ACI 2), disabling WMM
[53772.807642] wlan0: associate with  (try 1/3)
[53772.810355] wlan0: RX AssocResp from  (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[53772.810561] wlan0: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Nice script, you should add an option to cut out some more sensitive data like your own IP6, the wlan-ssids,  host this on https://github.com/

Comment: http://gist.github.com/ may actually be easier for a single script and it works without an account. :-]

Comment: I have no way of connecting to the internet (neither ethernet nor WiFi is working). How do I run the diagnostics?

Comment: There are directions for running the script with no internet here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2082305&p=12350385&viewfull=1#post12350385

Answer (score 29):

I would want everything in this script:

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info
```

It gathers all the information that I would like to see and, in most cases, correct any wireless problem.

After the report is created, I would want the result posted here: http://paste.ubuntu.com Then give us the link in your original question.

Comment: @LiveWireBT Wonder who those friends are that helped him with the script...

Comment: Ok I think I got it. My bad. :)

Comment: Looks nice and useful; however, I'd be somewhat reluctant to run a script off an URL - could you possibly mirror the content inside the answer?

Comment: You can certainly download it without running it and look at the code in gedit: wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script

Comment: Editted answer 28 Sept 2016 to link more recent version from github.

Answer (score 16):

What information do we need? This:

- What have you tried? What happened when you tried it?
- What do you mean by "doesn't work"? The indicator applet appears to show connectivity but you can't reach any web pages? The indicator applet is frozen? Not present? You can select a connection from the indicator applet but the password for that connection doesn't work?
- What is the make of your machine and which version of Ubuntu are you running?
- Has it ever worked? (ie, Did it work for a while and stop working? Did it work under Windows but not under Ubuntu? Did it work under 12.04 but not 13.10?)

The Ubuntu [Wireless Troubleshooting Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide) appears to be current, so that might be a place to start. Some useful commands there:

If your wireless has worked on this install before, and you want to troubleshoot a connection:

- `nm-tool` will give you a report on the state of your network manager and any attached devices.
- `rfkill` will enable or disable network devices. `rfkill --list` will list any available devices and provide some clues to their state. You may need to [run this as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207466/how-to-run-applications-as-root).
- `ifdown` and `ifup` will bring network interfaces up and down. If you've changed settings, stopping and starting (as root) with `ifdown wlan0` and `ifup wlan0` may help.
- Not sure what your network interfaces are even called? Try `ifconfig -a`

If you aren't sure you even have drivers installed, find out with `lshw` if your wireless card is built in, or `lspci` (for PCI cards -- less likely these days) or `lsusb` (for a USB wireless device). `lshw -C network` will display details of hardware in the "network" class, which is what you want. Again, you may need to [run this as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207466/how-to-run-applications-as-root).

Comment: Good questions, link looks promising and up to date.

Comment: Another reason for not detecting Wifi after new installations or such issues might be a problem with Network Adapter Drivers.

You can first check which Wifi Network Adapter is there in your PC.

lshw -C network .
Mine Wireless N/W adapter was Realtek rtl8723be. So I installed the drivers from :

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

Thanks.

Comment: nm-tool does not exist on my system (16.04)... need I get it from a specific location?