# Clonezilla and Alignment

Tags: grub2, backup, ssd, clone, clonezilla

I have to move my 14.04 system from my old SSD onto a new one. Having decided to use Clonezilla, I went for direct disk-to-image: this would have had the bootloader (grub) cloned as well, allowing to spare some headaches.

Now, I discovered that probably Clonezilla does NOT preserve partition alignment. This is a very bad thing for SSDs.

So, I decided to go for partition-to-image. Now, when I restore my system partition, grub shall be missing. How can I restore my system partition and have it properly loaded at startup?

Comment: A disk to disk clonezilla image preserves everything, including alignment.

Comment: May I ask for some authoritative source to confirm this claim?

Comment: Umm... it's kind of the whole point of the whole thing: every sector on the source is written exactly the same on the destination.

Comment: In this post: http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/restoring-image-with-clonezilla-general-questions.358902/, it is said clonezilla does not support auto-alignment (although I think that guy was moving from mechanical disk to ssd). I just want to be sure..

Comment: You're misreading Phillip (psusi). He said that alignment is *preserved*. There is no need for "auto-alignment" if both disks operate the same way regarding sectors, which is usually the case. However using soutions like clonezilla is a poor workaround and there is no reason to be scared of installing bootloaders. I recommed a [tar-backup](http://askubuntu.com/a/7811/40581) and reinstalling GRUB as described in the link (which I just edited to make it more clear for you).

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading your tutorial. But why you say Clonezilla is a poor way?