# WIndows SSD GPT with linux HDD MBR

Tags: dual-boot

Hello I have Windows 10 in a SSD with GPT and I have installed Ubuntu in another HDD(no GPT)
My problem is that GNU GRUB doesnt work at all and the first disk (the one with windows) always boots...if I want to run Ubuntu I must open the BIOS and select the other disk.I have tried to install GRUB in the disk where Windows is installed but it doesnt work either

Comment: UEFI and BIOS are not compatible. Windows only boots from gpt with UEFI. Ubuntu can boot from either gpt or MBR with BIOS and only directly from MBR with BIOS. And once you start booting in one mode you cannot change or from grub menu only can boot other installs in same boot mode. Better to also then have Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode on gpt drive. You should have a one time boot key like f10 or f12 to make dual booting from UEFI easier.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer ...so i try to convert another disk to GPT

Comment: Best to have really good backups. Converting to or from GPT
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html
 And you may then be able to reinstall grub & edit fstab with new UUIDs. But probably easier to reinstall, if you have good backups of /home, list of installed applications and any other data on drive.

Comment: Also, there is a way to use Windows 10's bootloader to launch Ubuntu: http://superuser.com/questions/499617/how-can-i-add-linux-to-the-new-windows-8-boot-manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to install an EFI system partition on the Ubuntu harddrive and keep the MBR scheme if you want and if there is still a free primary partition available, but for long term you should move the Ubuntu install to GPT. With the knowledge from the first link below you could make tar backups of your existing installation, create a GPT record, restore and just install GRUB as UEFI. That probably save you time setting up your configuration again.

- [Is it still possible to install Ubuntu to an external harddrive with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/559007/40581)
- [How to back up my entire system?](https://askubuntu.com/q/7809/40581)