# Backing up Trusty for Xenial

Tags: 14.04, backup, lts, 16.04

I want to install Xenial Xerus as soon as its final release is out but being an Ubuntu noob there's a fine chance that I might mess things up. I want to know if there's a way to back up my current installation so that I could recover it if things go wrong.

Edit: The wifi link wasn't related but [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/7813/462484) one is.

Comment: ...meant this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7809/how-to-back-up-my-entire-system

Comment: That link certainly helped. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem) you can use `tar` to make backup of whole your system in just one command:

```
sudo tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /
```

It will create `backup.tar.gz` archive in folder where you are in. You can change destination as you wish (e.g pendrive)

If you have your `home` on different partition you need to back it up separately, or omit `--one-file-system` flag and exclude such directries like  `/proc`, `/sys`, `/mnt`, `/media`, `/run` and `/dev`

---

There are also many others tools like `rsync` or `Déjà Dup`