# Why deja-dup fails with dependencies in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, deja-dup

I got many errors when first time trying to setup deja-dup. Now, I get only the following thing which is a similar warning as you get when python2-deprecation warnings.

[image]

The `install` button stays there all the time. You cannot start backup.

I do Ads20000's proposal successfully, which resolves the issue in the screenshot

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get remove deja-dup 
sudo apt-get install deja-dup
```

However, output when trying to write to NTFS disc, where you should be able to use NTFS disc as discussed [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2175442)

[image]

I think the only solution is here the following where I however cannot found the mounted NTFS disc: it is not in `/media/masi/`. I started it as root but the file-directory tree is so much different

```
gksu deja-dup-preferences
```

How can you find the backup disc now when doing backups as root? I am not sure if this is a good way to do backups so please correct if not.

[image]

System: Ubuntu 16.04
Deja-dup: 34.2
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
Linux kernel: 4.6

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Please use `ubuntu-bug deja-dup` to report the bug :) (and link to this question in your bug report)

Comment: Could you also try running, one after the other to see if this fixes the problem: `sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade`, then `sudo apt install -f`, then `sudo apt remove deja-dup ; sudo apt install deja-dup`

Comment: I've edited the answer with thoughts about your second problem. I think that you might have to use a different application for a full backup (but do report a bug for the issue, if someone complains that it's a feature request then ask that the bug is marked 'Wishlist')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the original issue, try the following commands:

To make sure your computer is fully up-to-date:

> sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade

To resolve any dependency issues which may exist:

> sudo apt install -f

To see if  reinstalling the program helps:

> sudo apt remove deja-dup ;  sudo apt install deja-dup

As for the issue with permissions, I'm not sure deja-dup does full backups very well because, as you have found, you have to run it as root and then you have problems with your mounted drive. Either just backup your home folder, or use a different tool ([see this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7809/how-to-back-up-my-entire-system), though having done some other Googling people seem to recommend Clonezilla a fair bit). [This Launchpad Question back from 2010](https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/138071) seems to suggest that deja-dup doesn't do full backups very well, maybe that issue hasn't been worked on much since then.

Comment: I think it can be a filesystem problem. Deja-dup works only with identical filesystems.I added comment to the bug report. https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/138071

Comment: I try to substitute now deja-dup, motivated by `tar czf` which should be efficient if it works, here http://askubuntu.com/q/788272/25388

Comment: Well that wasn't a bug report but a Launchpad Question, but at least it's on Launchpad somewhere. Fair enough, maybe you could format your external drive as ext4 and do the backup with deja-dup? Or just use a different tool...tell us when you find something that works!

Comment: Formatting is not the possible option always, like here. I think the best option is to just use tar/zip/... to make the backup, like the thread. Then, you do not lose permissions/owners etc when you do not need to switch filesystem. Current backup softwares do not allow such a feature internally. It is also so simple and fast to use just `tar czf`. I do not need to read my backups. They are used just in the case of failure.