# Ubuntu doesn't boot after making a system back up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04

Yesterday I wanted to increase my home directory size as I constantly got notified about critical amount of space. Firstly, as suggested in many topics, I wanted to do external back up of my system, so according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/7811/1039955) I did:

```
sudo tar czf /media/external-disk/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/dev --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/tmp --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/media /
```

Unfortunetely, after an hour of creating a back up the process ended in some error (I don't remember the exact notice but it wasn't very informative). So I decided to gave it up for yesterday and try again today's morning. Unfortunetely, when I open my laptop today Ubuntu doesn't boot at all:
[image]
The second message is something that used to pop out earlier, but usually there wary many lines of this message - now it's a one line back and back again. The first message (`recovering journal`) is something new though. How can I check why my Ubuntu doesn't boot up now? What might have gone wrong while backing up? How can I fix it now?

@Edit: I also installed Nvidia 4.30 driver yesterday, although I had a newer one (4.40) already installed. After that I restarted computer and Ubuntu booted without any problems, but maybe this is a reason behind my issue?

Comment: The recovering journal is usually an indication that the system was uncleanly shutdown prior session (ie. someone yanked out the power cord, held power button in etc) instead of cleanly shutting down. It is trying to repair that damage, the second line is the `fsck` (file system check) report on completion of required error check (the check also occurs every ~30 boots anyway, unless it detects an unclean shutdown).

Comment: Thanks. This `fsck` happened to me with every boot actually before, but after it generated few lines (and probably checked all the files) computer started normally. Now it kind of chokes on the first line. I started my computer several minutes ago and it seems to reboot every time after that first line.

Comment: If I see the `fsck` message and didn't expect it (ie. it's not been a lot of boots & thus 30th is plausible) I tend to shutdown as soon as possible (or SysRq cause clean shutdown), then boot 'live' media (eg. Ubuntu install media selecting 'try') and `fsck` the partition manually to ensure disk partition is fine. maybe check drive health (ie. SMART), check partitions look normal, before trying to reboot normally. Assuming that all looks good, I'd next boot without 'quiet splash' (on linux kernel line), then likely boot to runlevel 1 (add ' 1 ' to linux) to slowly boot, exploring for clues

Comment: I'm not sure I understood all your suggestions, but are you saying that unexpected `fsck` may be damaging to the hardware? Or indicate damage in the hardware?

Comment: Seeing it every boot strikes me as your system is regularly not cleanly shutting down & I'd have investigated that, treating it as a warning of potential problems could occur from whenever it started... (which could your issue now, so a bit late, but it maybe something else too). You mention the video drivers (numbers are just numbers, marketers don't have meaning so 430/440 doesn't relate to age, unless you're specific and include versions too. eg. 440.82 etc) I personally would be more suspicious of nvidia issues, and would consider backing out that change, but wait for advice from others

Comment: @karel I'm not sure, how can I get into command line to test this command if my boot is not finished?

Comment: To get a command prompt boot into recovery mode: https://askubuntu.com/a/859640/