# Cannot upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, 21.10

Since 21.10 isn't supported anymore, I'd like to upgrade to 22.04. However, running

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

gives the following output

```
...
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

But I can't install all available updates, since 21.10 isn't supported anymore. Running

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Just gives a lot of 404s since 21.10 isn't available anymore.

So what to do? I want to upgrade to 22.04, but have to update 21.10 before doing so. But I can't do that because it's not supported.

Comment: Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades for how to *manually* change your sources so you can apply all upgrades & then (*after reboot if required*) perform the *release-upgrade*.  Take note of EOL (9 months after release date) or EOL warning notices (6 weeks prior to EOL) in future.  *The additional step you now need to perform isn't required if you upgrade prior to EOL or very soon after; alas you missed that window*

Comment: Do note:  you mention both 21.10 & 20.10 and upgrade procedures differ for both (*a little; as 20.10 was QA-tested & supported to upgrade to 21.04 which is now EOL; 21.10 (*hirsute*) upgrades to 22.04 (*jammy*) which is supported*).  I've assumed you're using 21.10 as tagged & referenced as well; ignoring the 20.10 (*groovy*) you also reference.

Comment: Thanks, misspelling from my part, I meant 21.10 all the way. I've edited the post to correct that.

Answer (score 8):

Use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo sed -i 's/continue/pass/g' /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py
sudo sed -i 's/impish/jammy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
echo "Upgrade distro"
sudo do-release-upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install -f -y
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge -y
```

From :

https://github.com/daboynb/linux_scripts/blob/main/eol_to_jammy_source.sh

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73034540/an-upgrade-from-hirsute-to-jammy-is-not-supported-with-this-tool

Comment: Well done! This script worked perfectly for me! It took many hours to complete on my system, but overall, flawless!

Answer (score 1):

1. **Make a backup to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/source.list.d/*`, or [make a backup to the entire system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7809/how-to-back-up-my-entire-system) instead whenever possible.** You can then restore your system in case you messed it up.
2. In `/etc/apt/sources.list`, change all `impish` to `jammy`.
3. Comment out all entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` (recommended) or change all `impish` to `jammy` (not recommended, as not all third-party repositories are ready for 22.04).
4. Run `sudo apt update`

   - Comment out the entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` if they failed to upgrade
5. Run `sudo apt full-upgrade`
6. Reboot your computer. Your computer should boot into 22.04 now.
7. Restore the entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` (if you commented them out in step 3, but do not forget to change all `impish` to `jammy`), then run `sudo apt update` to check for updates and repository availability.

Note that when editing the source files, [you should **never** use `sudo gedit /etc/apt/source.list`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications). Use `gedit admin:///etc/apt/source.list` or use a command-line text editor (`nano` is a simple and fast one) instead.

Comment: I think the command in 5 should be `sudo apt full-upgrade` right?

Comment: i recommend clonezilla.org for partition and/or disk backup.