# How to back up and restore entire system?

Tags: backup

Colleagues of ours want to use our research teams ML computer for a while. Because of data security, we can't give them the machine as is. It would be nice if I could backup the entire system, install a clean version of ubuntu and hand it to them. When they are done, they can return it, and we reinstall our backup.

Is there a way to do this? I'm talking about an exact copy, so ideally I don't need to do much work when it comes back, just "copy back" our stored backup file and boot it up. Installing the correct cuda versions and drivers as well as the python environments was quite the pain, and I'd like to avoid having to do that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to back up my entire system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7809/how-to-back-up-my-entire-system)

Comment: There are many ways to do it, a simple *clone* of the drive itself, can be restored; with that working regardless of OS too.  You didn't specify what Ubuntu product, what architecture or any specifics beyond the *vague* Ubuntu (is this a server? desktop? *snap* only (Core) system etc, as not all backup options cover all products though many do)

Comment: @guiverc, Our version is Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. Regarding the question you tagged: Do I just run the command specified on a clean version of ubuntu, and it overwrites everything with the backed up files? Including all installed programs and drivers? Not a CS guy, sorry, just a medical researcher.

Comment: Ahh sorry, Can't read apparently. As I understand it I boot a ubuntu version from a stick, then mount the machine under /mnt and then copy everything from the backup version there. That will overwrite it and have the system in the same exact state as it was before, correct?

Comment: I am not a fan of image backups. But if you have a lot of configuration in / (root), that may be better for you. Generally your backup, regular & automatic, should include everything to allow you to do a new install & completely restore system. You do have a good backup? Many suggest this for image backups, never used it. http://clonezilla.org/. With my desktop I export list of installed apps & rsync, although rdiff considered better for servers or commercial systems. That backup worked to install to several different systems at different times.

Comment: I'm not a great person to advise; as I don't use my own backups... If a system needs to be replaced, I use that as a chance to install fresh, and just restore data (*usually restore before I do install; and non-destructively install the new OS over data*). I've volunteered at a recycler where for *builds* we inserted a drive with *cloned* system (*modified Ubuntu Desktop with MATE added as well at the time*) & booted to confirm the *cloned* drive worked on hardware (*hardware always differed*). Cloning just duplicates the drive contents & so OS/setup & all on it just gets copied.